# in my apache2 site pointing only working /var/www/ only how to point outside the /folder in ubuntu(/root )

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, devops

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ovenfresh.codilar.net Port 80

my path /home/oven/www

Answer (score 0):

> in apche2 configuration file u have to add the folder
>
> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

then add this line

`<Directory /bar/bhtl/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

you can add your path